# Authenticating GCP service account with Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-storage, bitbucket-pipelines

Currently trying to authenticate the Linux machine in a bitbucket pipeline to run this code within a test that allows it to move a file from a GCS bucket to itself.

```
storage_client = storage.Client()

source_bucket = storage_client.bucket('gs://xxxx')
source_blob = source_bucket.blob(xxxx)

_ = source_bucket.copy_blob(source_blob, 'xxxx', destination_blob_name)
```

In order to authenticate I put this in the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` at the repository root directory:

```
image: python:3.8

options:
  max-time: 20

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        size: 2x
        caches:
          - pip
          - pipenv
        script:
          - curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-365.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
          - tar -xvf google-cloud-sdk-365.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
          - ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
          - export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/google-cloud-sdk/bin
          - echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY | gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=-
          - pip3 install -U pip pipenv
          - pipenv install --deploy --dev
          - gcloud auth list
          - pipenv run pytest -v --junitxml=test-reports/report.xml
```

Where `GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY` is a repository variable on Bitbucket. However when the line `pipenv run pytest -v --junitxml=test-reports/report.xml` is run, I get the error:

```
>       storage_client = storage.Client()
tests/gcs/test_gcs.py:58: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/build-3vGKWv3F/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py:124: in __init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(
/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/build-3vGKWv3F/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py:318: in __init__
    _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project, credentials=credentials)
/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/build-3vGKWv3F/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py:266: in __init__
    project = self._determine_default(project)
/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/build-3vGKWv3F/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py:285: in _determine_default
    return _determine_default_project(project)
/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/build-3vGKWv3F/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py:186: in _determine_default_project
    _, project = google.auth.default()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
scopes = None, request = None, quota_project_id = None, default_scopes = None
    def default(scopes=None, request=None, quota_project_id=None, default_scopes=None):
        """Gets the default credentials for the current environment.
    
        `Application Default Credentials`_ provides an easy way to obtain
        credentials to call Google APIs for server-to-server or local applications.
```

Now some people would want to save the `GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY` as a file on the repository or somehow copy it to the linux machine running the pipeline itself, but I think it's best if we use the line `echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY | gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=-` and not commit any private keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command **gcloud auth activate-service-account** does not set up ADC (Application Default Credentials) for the python program.

Write the contents of the service account to a file and set the environment variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** to point to the file.

Another option is write the contents to a known location and then specify that location when creating the client:

```
storage.Client.from_service_account_json('<PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON>')
```

There are additional options such as creating the credentials from a JSON string that you pass to the Python program. Typically you would base64 encode/decode first.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(str)
storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
```